# How to make two countdown timer which if one start but another will stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make multiple countdown timer that I place in every tab. When I clicked a tab the countdown will start but in another countdown in another tab will stop. Can I make this happened?
Somebody, help me please ...

Comment: Can you? Sure. But w/o a specific question other than "how do I do this" you're unlikely to get help on SO. What *specifically* are you having an issue with?

Comment: Next time I will  do it. Thank you about your suggestion, Mr. Newton. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setInterval() & clearInterval to handle your timers.
Make click events on the tabs & clear the timers you want to stop, you can also reset the timer if that's what you need.

```
var interval_1 = null, interval_2 = null, timer_1 = 0, timer_2 = 0;
$("#tab1").click(function()
{
    clearInterval(interval_2);
    interval_1 = setInterval(function(){ 
        timer_1++; 
    }, 1000); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v0owsqym/

Answer (score 1):

You can handle setInterval() in javascript separately, working like instances.
It's possible to clear them and start again, seems like what you want to do. 
To set each timer you can do it:

```js
var interval_1 = null, interval_2 = null, timer_1 = 0, timer_2 = 0;

interval_1 = setInterval(function(){ 
  timer_1++; 
  console.log('interval_1: ' + timer_1); 
}, 1000); 

interval_2 = setInterval(function(){ 
  timer_2++; 
  console.log('interval_2: ' + timer_2); 
}, 2000);
```

To clear each instance you can do easily:

```
clearInterval(interval_1); // Based on the first example
```

SO you just need to clear the timer setting it to 0 and start it again.